# While creating dummy variables with n values why cant we just create a single variable?

Tags: regression, linear, categorical-encoding

For a variable that can take on n values, we create n-1 dummy variables, and that part is perfectly understood by me, but why cant we just create a single variable and load it with n unique values. For example if we have a categorical variable which can take on 3 values-India, USA, UK. We can simply create a single variable and put India=0, USA=1, UK=2, whats the problem with doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the regression model which would have the variables coded as indicated, but which is passed as a single column instead of dummies.

If India is the reference group, then the coefficient for country would be $\beta$.  It would represent the difference in the outcome between India and the USA.  Now, $2\beta$ would represent the difference between UK and India *but forcing the effect to be twice that of the effect between USA and India seems a bit restrictive*.  Its better to freely estimate the effects of each country in comparison to the reference group, which is what we get when we use dummies.